# Given an array; how do I run a function for the first element and conditionally wait, return, or run the function for the next element?

Tags: javascript, node.js, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I have set of functions on Parse Cloud that query a node/mongo API that I have running externally.

One of these functions gives me an array of active user objectIds, each of which map to a message channel name ordered by distance.

I need to take this array of objectIds and starting with the first element:

1. Send a message;
2. Set a timeout (I'll try 30 seconds while testing, but could be anything greater in prod);
3. If, during the timeout I receive an 'unavailable' response then ditch the remaining time, move on to the next element and go back to 1;
4. If, during the timeout I receive an 'available' response, then exit the loop, forget about all the other elements and return success.
5. If I get no responses at all, return failure.

I'm not sure if Parse CloudCode is the right tool for this job so I've tagged node in case I need to put the logic in the API instead.

JS is still young in this one so answers that have a bit of depth or allow me to learn something that will answer my question are appreciated and upvoted.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with Parse CloudCode, but could answer this in node. Is this a node question at all? Do you have access to npm packages?

Comment: I sure do. I wrote the node/mongo api myself and have full control over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a matter of control flow, and an option would be the `async` package, or a Promise library.

Let's look at the async library. We could approach this with the [detectSeries](https://github.com/caolan/async#detect) function.

```
//Might need this, if you need to stop the processing when it wasn't really a success, 
//since detectSeries doesn't handle errors
var specialFlag = false;

function doYourLogic( item, callback ){
   sendMessage( item.whatever, function( err, result ){
     if( result.status === 'available' ){
       //flag this item as the one that worked. This will break the detectSeries
       callback(true);
     }
     //whether any other error, just move on to the next
     callback(false);

   }
}

//Iterate over the entire collection, running the function 'doYourLogic' on each item, 
//where 'finalDetect' is called once everything is done 
//(either a single item passed the test, or all failed and the result is undefined)
async.detectSeries( collection, doYourLogic, 
  function finalDetect( result ){
    if( result === undefined ){
      //none of the items returned true, so nothing passed
    }
    //the result is the item that was successful
    var usefaulData = result.field1;
}
```

We could approach this with a few other of the async functions, but the idea of that package is to manage the control flow of all these asynchronous calls - and make sure they happen in order. A Promise library might be helpful too, but no necessary and probably not worth the trouble at this time.

Comment: I haven't had chance to fully implement the ideas here yet, but it makes sense to me. I'll action the answer when I've had a go. Thanks @clay

Comment: I've marked that as answered as it solves 90% of the problem. At what point in the code above could I put a timeout in? For example, to wait 30 seconds for a response before I go to the next call in the series.

Comment: In the function `doYourLogic()`, likely as an option to the `sendMessage()` call. `doYourLogic` will not continue the async.series until a callback is called. When making a call to another service (say, an http request), often there is a timeout option that will make the call result in an error if the time takes too long. Seeing your own timeout is trickier, because you'd need a lot of logic to ensure you don't call a callback twice (like, if it takes 31 seconds, and you already called back "invalid", your logic would likely callback as "valid" . . . then everything's all screwy ; )

Comment: I've had to unmark this as answered as `detectSeries` tests a truth for every `item` that exists in `collection`, reports on truth or not, but continues to keep running the function. It doesn't quit on first truth.

Comment: You might have ran into [this bug](https://github.com/caolan/async/issues/534). Looks like [there have been releases recently](https://github.com/caolan/async/releases), what version of async are you using?

Comment: You were right re the bug. I've marked the question as answered. Thanks again.

Comment: Cool, glad you found it! Thanks for coming back : )